# How to interpolate whole SQL query in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

In slick, I could

```
sql"""SELECT C1 FROM T1""".as[Int].head
```

But I could not use a variable in the SQL

```
val ss = "SELECT C1 FROM T1"
sql"""${ss}""".as[Int].head
```

Is there some solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of `#$` for splicing literal values can be useful in this scenario. Check [Splicing Literal Values](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/sql.html#splicing-literal-values) for more info.